# Dependency Properties in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I'm struggling to understand Dependency Properties in Silverlight 2. Does anybody have a good explanation or link that clearly explains the DependencyObject and/or DependencyProperty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops! forgot to insert

http://www.deepinconcept.net/post/2008/10/31/Silverlight-20-Dependency-Properties-And-Routed-Events.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I like this article that "**Jesse Liberty - Silverlight Geek**" blogged called:
**[Dependency Property System – Deeper Dive Part 1](http://jesseliberty.com/2008/09/30/dependency-property-system-%E2%80%93-deeper-dive-part-1/)**.

It really explains the need for Dependency Properties and how to create your own, without having to read a novel to get what you need.

Comment: Jesse Liberty is a mine of information and tutorials when it comes to Silverlight - his blog is definitely recommended.